# Proxy multiple hosts that have same URL patterns

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I am using [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) to proxy my API calls

How can I proxy multiple target hosts? I have searched through the issue and still could not understand.

https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/12 - Allow me to use proxy table but what should link should I put for `target`? Because I have multiple targets.

I am thinking of pattern matching to proxy multiple hosts but another problem would arise because I have a few hosts with almost the same URL link.

Example

- https://website1.com/api/v1.1/{endpoint}
- https://website2.com/api/{endpoint}
- https://api.website3.com/api/{endpoint}

Tried some solutions below but dosen't work

Solution 1

```
const proxyOptions = proxy({
  target: ["https://website1.com", "https://website2.com", "https://api.website3.com"],
  changeOrigin: true,
  loglevel: "debug"
});
```

Solutuon 2

```
const proxyTable = {
  "/api": ["https://website1.com", "https://website2.com", "https://api.website3.com"]
};

const proxyOptions = proxy({
  target: "http://localhost:3000",
  router: proxyTable,
  changeOrigin: true,
  loglevel: "debug"
});
```

Solution 3

```
server.use(
      proxy("/api", { target: "https://website1.com", changeOrigin: true }),
      proxy("/api", { target: "https://website2.com", changeOrigin: true }),
      proxy("/api", { target: "https://api.website3.com", changeOrigin: true })
    );
```

Mounting the proxy

```
server.use("/api", proxyOptions)
```

Thanks for looking into this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the solution using `pathRewrite`

```
const website1 = proxy({
  target: "https://website1.com",
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    "^/website1": "/api"
  },
  loglevel: "debug"
});

const website2 = proxy({
  target: "https://website2.com",
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    "^/website2": "/api"
  },
  loglevel: "debug"
});

const website3 = proxy({
  target: "https://api.website3.com",
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    "^/website3": "/api"
  },
  loglevel: "debug"
});
```

Mounting the server

```
const server = express();

server.use("/website1", website1);
server.use("/website2", website2);
server.use("/website3", website3);
```

However, this will give my website alot pages that I do not need like `http://localhost:3000/website1` and etc.

Are there any ways to hide these pages or display something else instead of the homepages of websites that I am using.

Sorry, I am still learning node.js please be patience with me.